# React Native: Handle silent push notification

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

Im using [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for handling push notification for our React Native app (for android and iOS).

I noticed that there is only have 1 callback for a push notification that is received when the app is running (foreground or background) and not when its closed or killed.

```
firebase
.notifications()
.onNotification(notification => {
    console.log('Notification received');
);
```

But if the app is closed or killed, it will just put the notification in the tray and will not execute the console.log above.

Then enter silent push notification. So when I just send data part in the payload of the notification and even if app is in foreground, the callback above wont be triggered.

I don't see other callbacks that would help on receiving silent push notifications.

So how do we handle push notification in the javascript part?

Comment: i am also having the same issue but i am using OneSignal for push notification services! i have reached about learning a headless js component

Comment: maybe we could make a chat room to discuss this together

Comment: also there are some other packages like react-native-background, react-native-fetch, react-native-qeue , that are helpfull in the scenario for both ios and android! i am looking into those too!  can you share what you have searched so far! please

Comment: Right now, I have not looked into other RN libraries for push notification; only this one. I was able to handle silent push notification in the Android part. but it got some complications like if I handle it there, then the javascript callbacks stop working.

Comment: you made a background service for this or something! can you please share about it sir!

Comment: There maybe a way like I handle the raw notification first in Android and check if its a silent type. If yes, I will do my that logic there in Android. And if it is not a silent notification, then I will pass it to the javascript part and let it handle there.

Comment: @Rizwanatta Ya. Just like creating a simple android app with firebase https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186775/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-iori24).

Comment: @Rizwanatta Im back to this problem. lol. after 1 month. Have u managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: well actually yes i have!

Comment: wow! Can share it with us?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need additional packages like suggested in other answers.
Use RNFirebase.io, you can handle this easily.

If you receive Notification if App is in Background, you have to handle it by your own to display this Notification. As an example see my init-Method for Push-Notifications.

```
  import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
  const notifications = firebase.notifications();
  ....
  notifications.onNotification((notif) => {
    notif.android.setChannelId('app-infos');
    notifications.displayNotification(notif);
  });
```

You do it with `displayNotification`. But make sure, that you set the Notification-Channel before calling it, because else it wouldn't work on >= Android 8.0

**BTW**: *Make sure, that you fully setup Firebase and grant all needed Permissions to be able to listen for Notifications if App is closed or in Background. (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android)*

## Appendix

I add this as example to show how I implemented the *firebase-notification-stuff* as a tiny library (remove the redux-stuff if you don't need it):

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { saveNotificationToken } from 'app/actions/firebase';
import reduxStore from './reduxStore';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
const notifications = firebase.notifications();
const crashlytics = firebase.crashlytics();

function registerNotifChannels() {
  try {
    // Notification-Channels is a must-have for Android >= 8
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      'app-infos',
      'App Infos',
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
    ).setDescription('General Information');

    notifications.android.createChannel(channel);
  } catch (error) {
    crashlytics.log(`Error while creating notification-channel \n ${error}`);
  }
}

// This is the Promise object that we use to initialise the push
// notifications. It will resolve when the token was successfully retrieved. The
// token is returned as the value of the Promise.
const initPushNotifs = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const isPermitted = await messaging.hasPermission();

    if (isPermitted) {
      registerNotifChannels();

      try {
        const token = await messaging.getToken();
        if (token) {
          resolve(token);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        crashlytics.log(`Error: failed to get notification-token \n ${error}`);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    crashlytics.log(`Error while checking notification-permission\n ${error}`);
  }

  // If we get this far then there was no token available (or something went
  // wrong trying to get it)
  reject();
});

function init() {
  // Initialise the push notifications, then save the token when/if it's available
  initPushNotifs.then(token => reduxStore.dispatch(saveNotificationToken(token)));

  // Save the (new) token whenever it changes
  messaging.onTokenRefresh(token => reduxStore.dispatch(saveNotificationToken(token)));

  notifications.onNotification((notif) => {
    notif.android.setChannelId('app-infos');
    notifications.displayNotification(notif);
  });

  notifications.onNotificationOpened((notif) => {
    const { notification: { _data: { chatroom: chatRoomId } } = {} } = notif;

    if (chatRoomId) {
      NavigationService.navigate('ChatRoom', { chatRoomId });
    }
  });
}

export default {
  init,
};
```

With this, only go to your index.js file (or your root-file for your app, how ever it will be named) and call the init-Metod:

```
...
import LPFirebase from 'lib/LPFirebase';

LPFirebase.init();
```

Comment: onNotification is only triggered when the app is up (foreground or background). The scenario here if the app is killed or closed. So your javascript part wont be called at all.

Comment: Strange, because it works for me. I've created a small library to connect firebase and call my init()-Method in my index.js. I will enhance the above Comment so you cann see, how it work for me.

Comment: Hi there again. Is it possible for u to share your whole code?